# is there any standalone installer for NPM windows?

Tags: npm

Is there standalone setup installer for NPM windows?

The purpose is to install NPM without using internet connection

Comment: Well, you would need internet connection to download but try having a look here, it has an installer and even the source if you want to compile it yourself: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing NPM or Node.js requires an Internet connection. Even using cmd to install it, They download the files first in the background from the node.js website. Then, installing it. Or you can download it from the [Node.js Official website](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Edit: Yeah there is but you still need to download it online.